# Coercing type with optional properties to an indexable type

Tags: typescript

Typescript throws an error when trying to pass a type with optional properties as an indexable type: ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQV9TCKoCMA-AFxQDOwATsingUYwEyU32PP6uoBmTkgCuAWwBGEOjgC+OHAGMA9klpQAglXiMM2eTgBmIpIuAJVUMHWWKI1agHkJAKwhmoACmWuqWKADaANYQIFS0DKgAuuHcqFAAPlCiktJQsgCUsZFouARQdBDAInRIUABEwPbA5XIKKmrKADYQAHQAhg7SwJ7WtvZOru49GhkY6JiV1eUZQA))

```js
type Thing = {
    thing1?: string
    thing2?: string
    thing3?: number
}

const thing: Thing = {}

function processObject (obj: { [key: string]: string | number }): string {
    /* Generic object handler, not specifically for Thing */
    return "test"
}

console.assert(processObject(thing) === "test")
```

This results in:

> Error: Argument of type 'Thing' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string | number; }'. Property 'thing1' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

Of course, it works if the argument's type is forcibly made optional:

```js
function processObject (obj: { [key: string]: string | number | undefined }): string {
    return "test"
}
```

I don't see why this is necessary, though. According to [TS PR #7029](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029), the indexable type should be compatible with other types that have the same implicit index signature.

Whether or not those properties are optional is irrelevant - that property should simply not be present on the object - right? Why do I have to specify `undefined`? Is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the following line will compile without warning according to your definition of `Thing`:

```
const A: Thing = { thing2: undefined };
```

This makes the error when calling `processObject()` *technically correct*; you might end up reading an `undefined` value from the object when you expect only a `string` or a `number`.

---

Explanation:

TypeScript doesn't always distinguish situations where a value (like an object property or function parameter) is *missing* from those where the value is *present but `undefined`*.  This confusion is inherited from JavaScript, where the difference can be subtle: if I have a JavaScript object named `obj`, and `obj.prop === undefined` is `true`, I can't tell if `"prop" in obj` is true or false from that.

There's a longstanding open issue in GitHub, [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195), asking for some consistency around distinguishing "missing" from `undefined` in TypeScript.  Optional properties are treated like both "possibly missing" and "possibly `undefined`", while the reverse, a required property with `| undefined` in its definition is *not* allowed to be missing.  Right now there's no way to say "I want a property that could be missing but if it is present it *should not* be `undefined`".

Additionally, [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) also suffer from doublethink in the opposite direction: in practice you can get `undefined` property values from them (since any given property might be missing) but the compiler doesn't acknowledge this (and acts like every possible property is present and defined).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) for the suggestion to include `undefined` automatically in the domain of index signature properties, and for the zillions of comments about it.  There is an upcoming feature flag called `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#39560](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39560)) which aims to address this, but even if you turn it on you still get the same problem with your code, so it doesn't fully fix it in all cases.

This mismatch between how missing and `undefined` values are dealt with in optional properties versus how they are dealt with in index signatures is the cause of your problem.

---

In my opinion the way to deal with this is just to add that `undefined` to your index signature and explicitly acknowledge that optional properties might be present but `undefined`.  It's not ideal, but is at least closer to consistent that way.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQV9TCKoCMA-AFxQDOwATsingUYwEyU32PP6uoBmTkgCuAWwBGEOjgC+OHAGMA9klpQAglXiMM2QsRRsqIpABMIAM2QQzUWQG4Fl04uAJVUMHWWKI1agB5CQArCDcACmVQqiwoAG0AawgQKloGVABdNO5UKAAfKFFJaXsAShyMtFwCKDoIYBE6JCgAImB-YFa5BRU1ZQAbCAA6AEMA6WAI719-INDwqY0yjHRMds7WsoUgA)

Answer (score 0):

This no longer reproduces in TypeScript 4.2 due to this change: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2-rc/#relaxed-rules-between-optional-properties-and-string-index-signatures (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41921).